# Como popular lista de Objetos com resultado de select(C# e MySQL)?

Tags: c#, mysql, lista

```
string strSQL = "SELECT usuperm.idusuario, usuperm.codfunc, usuperm.perm FROM usuperm INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.idusuario = usuperm.idusuario WHERE usuarios.loginusuario = @loginusuario AND usuarios.senhausuario = @senhausuario";
MySqlCommand cmdSQL = new MySqlCommand(strSQL, Conexao.Abrir());
cmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("loginusuario", loginusuario);
cmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("senhausuario", senhausuario);


MySqlDataReader drPerm = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
List<PropPerm> listPermn;


//... daqui não sei se uso foreach while ou if
```

Answer (score 1):

Opa, Valeu Igor, mas eu não consegui fazer da mesma maneira que você mostrou, andei pensando melhor e decidi que seria melhor utilizar um DataTable, fiz da seguinte forma e está Funcionando:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT usuperm.idusuario, usuperm.codfunc, usuperm.perm FROM usuperm INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.idusuario = usuperm.idusuario WHERE usuarios.loginusuario = @loginusuario AND usuarios.senhausuario = @senhausuario";
MySqlCommand cmdSQL = new MySqlCommand(strSQL, Conexao.Abrir());
cmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("loginusuario", loginusuario);
cmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("senhausuario", senhausuario);
MySqlDataReader drPerm = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();

DataTable perm = new DataTable();

if (drPerm.HasRows == true)
{
    perm.Load(drPerm);

    return perm;
}
else
{
    return perm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer com `while`:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT usuperm.idusuario, usuperm.codfunc, usuperm.perm FROM usuperm INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.idusuario = usuperm.idusuario WHERE   usuarios.loginusuario = @loginusuario AND usuarios.senhausuario =    @senhausuario";
MySqlCommand cmdSQL = new MySqlCommand(strSQL, Conexao.Abrir());
cmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("loginusuario", loginusuario);
cmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("senhausuario", senhausuario);

MySqlDataReader drPerm = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
List<PropPerm> listPermn = new List<PropPerm>();
while(drPerm.Read())
{
    PropPerm pp = new PropPerm() {
        //suas propriedades. Ex:
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(drPerm["id"]);
    };
    listPermn.Add(pp);
}
drPerm.Close();
cmdSQL.Close();
```

---

## Veja também

Aconselho que você dê uma olhada no bloco `using`.
Ele garante que sempre serão encerrados recursos como conexão, comando e leitor.

[Aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-o-bloco-using-no-c/16967) tem um post do DevMedia sobre isso.